# Modify css by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change two properties of a css, One property Value I want to modify using function call and other one is direct property assigning. I want to add background image at run time and setting property no repeat as well. Following two functions i came to know:

```
$(selector).css(property,function(index,currentvalue)) for changing value by function call and   other one is :-
$(selector).css({property:value, property:value, ...}) for assigning property.
```

Here I have two properties One is by function call and other one is direct property. I tried following code:

```
$('.xl21684').css('background-image', function () {
return 'url(' + imgs[parseInt(this.innerHTML)] + ')'
})
 $('.xl21684').css({background-repeat: no-repeat})
```

But it's not working at all.

Comment: What error messages do you have in the console? (the second on will give you a syntax error)

Comment: `{background-repeat: no-repeat}` is a syntax error. Try `{ "background-repeat": "no-repeat" }` instead, or pass two strings to `css()` instead of an object.

Comment: `$('.xl21684').css({ 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat' })`

Comment: need to add some quotes on keys and values,

Comment: Is it okey to modify same css multiple times??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to go your own way then don't forget to quote the property and value for proper result as @Cerbrus said:

```
('.xl21684').css({'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});
```

But you can try just once too:

```
$('.xl21684').css('background', function () {
return 'url(' + imgs[parseInt(this.innerHTML)] + ') no-repeat';
});
```

---

As per your comment you can use background shorthand property like below:

```
background: [background-color] [background-image] [background-repeat] [background-attachment] [background-position];
```

Comment: @C-link, What if I want to do background-position:center ?

Comment: ...no-repeat center';

Answer (score 1):

The first `.css()` seems to be fine. The second one just needs some quotes:

```
$('.xl21684').css({"background-repeat": "no-repeat"});
//                 ^                 ^  ^         ^
```

That should work.